# undefined reference to `zscal_' when using LAPACK compilation linking C++ to LAPACK in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, lapack

I have installed Lapack in Ubuntu, and while I am trying to compile
some C++ code linking to Lapack I am getting the following error,
Please let me know how to resolve the following issue.

//usr/local/lib/liblapack.a(zung2l.o): In function `zung2l_': zung2l.f:(.text+0x294): undefined reference to` zscal_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Thanks in advance.
[screenshort of the error is attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frDZD.png)

Comment: Do you **link** with LAPACK? Specifying it in includes is not enough.

Comment: Can you show us the last command before the error is thrown? Even better: show us the makefile.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! `zscal` is part of blas, http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d2/d74/zscal_8f.html . Could you try to link blas ? Something like `-llapack -lblas -lm` to link lapack, blas and the math library.